# Create Individual DataFrames From a List of csv Files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a folder of csv files that I'd like to loop over to create individual DataFrames named after the file itself.
So if I have `file_1.csv`, `file_2.csv`, `file_3.csv` ... I'd like DataFrames created for each file and have the df named after the file of the data it contains.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
# get list of all files
all_files = os.listdir("./Data/")

# get list of only csv files
csv_files = list(filter(lambda f: f.endswith('.csv'), all_files))

# remove file extension to get name only
file_names = []
for i in csv_files:
    file = i[:-4]
    file_names.append(file)
    
# create DataFrames from each file named after the corresonding file
dfs = []
def make_files_dfs():
    for a,b in zip(file_names, csv_files):
        if a == b[:-4]:
            a = pd.read_csv(eval(f"'Data/{b}'"))
            dfs.append(a)
```

error code:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 70 fields in line 7728, saw 74
```

---

#### **Update 1**

- using `chdir` instead of `listdir`
- replacing the `lambda` with `glob`
- two new attempts using response suggestions

new attempt 1:

```
path = "./Data/"
os.chdir(path)

csv_files = glob.glob("*.csv")

dataFrameDict = {}
def make_files_dfs():
    for a in csv_files:
        dataFrameDict[a[:-4] , pd.read_csv(a)]
```

Error Code:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'DataFrame'

I feel like this needs a line to append the dicts to a list; will mess with it.

new attempt 2:

```
path = "./Data/"
os.chdir(path)

csv_files = glob.glob("*.csv")

for i in range(len(csv_files)):
    globals()[f"df_{i}"] = pd.read_csv(csv_files[i])
```

Error code:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 70 fields in line 7728, saw 74

---

#### **Update 2**

- instead of trying to create a list of DataFrames, attempting to create a dictionary of DataFrames.  Turns out the error code was from one file having extra columns of data in one record, as @Jon Clements pointed out.

```
path = "./Data/"
os.chdir(path)

csv_files = glob.glob("*.csv")

csv_names = []
for i in csv_files:
    name = i[:-4]
    csv_names.append(name)
    
zip_object = zip(csv_names, csv_files)

df_collection = {}
for name, file in zip_object:
    df_collection[name] = pd.read_csv(file, low_memory=False)
```

Comment: I'd start by taking a look at the file that's causing `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 70 fields in line 7728, saw 74` to work out what's going on with that file and worry about the concatenation later...

Comment: Line 7728 has too many commas.

Comment: loading that particular file alone does not raise an error so, the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit difficult to understand. You have some unnecessary functions. First of all, it is easier to change the working directory path (by `os.chdir(path)`. Secondly, you can get rid of your lambda function and use `glob.glob`. Lastly, you cannot make a DataFrame named after a variable. Your `dfs` list will hold some class names that won't give you much insight into the DataFrame. It is much better to use a dictionary. Overall, this is how your code can look like:

```
import os
import glob

path = "the path to your data"
os.chdir(path)

# get list of only csv files
csv_files = glob.glob("/*.csv")

# create a dictionary with key as the DF name and values as DataFrames 
dataFrameDictionary={}
def make_files_dfs():
    for a in csv_files:
        dataFrameDictionary[a[:-4], pd.read_csv(a)]
```

Comment: yeah, that lambda is unnecessary and your line provided is cleaner.  I'm getting a new error message with the suggested make_files_dfs() that I think has to do with the enumeration, maybe it needs a counter?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why your code is so lengthy, but this can be done by following:

```
csv_list = ['file_1.csv', 'file_2.csv', 'file_3.csv']
for i in range(len(csv_list)):
    globals()[f"df_{i}"] = pd.read_csv(csv_list[i])
```

**Output:**

Three dataframes will be created. df_1 will have 1st file in the list, df_2 will have 2nd file in the list and so on..

Comment: I'd like to automate the creation of csv_list since there will be dozens of files in production and not just three.  I'm working with your suggested for loop to see if I can make progress.

Comment: @Matan If you want to automate the list creation, use os.listdir(path_of_directory_with_csv_files) and assign it to csv_list.